# Syntax Error in Insert Query

Tags: vb.net

Showing Syntax error in Insert Query...........
Error

```
           Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
```

but i have checked the query and tested it but there is no error Is there any problem in my code below...........Please any help thanks in advance

```
Sub OnOk()
        Dim strquerry2 As String
        Dim regcommand As OleDbCommand
        Try
            struser = txtuser.Text
            strpwd = txtpwd.Text
            strusertype = cmbbxutype.Text
            If openconnection() Then
                strquerry2 = "INSERT INTO Users(UserName , Password , UserType) VALUES('" & struser & "','" & strpwd & "','" & strusertype & "')"
                regcommand = New OleDbCommand(strquerry2, strcon)
                regcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End If
            strcon.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " " & ex.Source)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: is usertype a string or an int?

Comment: Query seems ok check table and column names and there datatype once.

Comment: Thanks Sir,it is text(string) I have checked all the concerned Tables,columns, connection every thing is fine but still throwing exception

Comment: Can you break the code after it constructs the strquerry2 and post that please. Should look like "INSERT INTO Users(UserName, Password,UserType) VALUES ('BOB', 'PASS', 'ADMIN')

Comment: thanks now i got it from Kelly

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for inconvenience.........Above code was not in an uderstanable formate

Sub OnOk()

Dim strquerry2 As String

Dim regcommand As OleDbCommand

Try

struser = txtuser.Text

strpwd = txtpwd.Text

strusertype = cmbbxutype.Text
            I
f openconnection() Then

strquerry2 = "INSERT INTO Users(UserName , Password , UserType) VALUES('" & struser & "','" & strpwd & "','" & strusertype & "')"

regcommand = New OleDbCommand(strquerry2, strcon)

regcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

End If

strcon.Close()

Catch ex As Exception

MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " " & ex.Source)

End Try

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

Password is apparently a reserved word. Place square brackets [] around it.

```
strquerry2 = "INSERT INTO Users(UserName , [Password] , UserType) VALUES('" & struser & "','" & strpwd & "','" & strusertype & "')"
```

Comment: Thanks Kelly............. Yes this was the real problem again thanks for your in time response